# RStudio - Plots in multiple windows

Tags: plot, rstudio

I'm using RStudio, and I want to view plots in a separate window to the console. How can I do this?

*Additional Information*

- Windows 7
- RStudio version 3.2.2 (32 bit)
- Currently running a "Swirl" lesson, so the plots pop up automatically as I advance down the console

[R Studio - Plots in one window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UrHw.png)

Comment: Does the "zoom" button in that screenshot do what you want?

Answer (score 6):

using `x11()` should get what you want, plots on separate window.

```
x11()
plot(cars)
```

Comment: The plot can be save as .jpeg in the working directory with `savePlot(filename = "myplot.jpeg", device = dev.cur())`.